# Multiple bindingRoutingKey's for a consumer with Spring Cloud Stream using RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'd like to configure an input channel in Spring Cloud Stream to be bound to the same exchange (destination) with multiple routing keys. I've managed to get this working with a single routing key like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          input1:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: key1.#
      bindings:
        input1:
          binder: rabbit
          group: group1
          destination: dest-group1
```

But I cannot seem to get it working for multiple keys. I've tried this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          input1:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: key1.#,key2.#
      bindings:
        input1:
          binder: rabbit
          group: group1
          destination: dest-group1
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.1 and Spring cloud dependencies are imported from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Finchley.RC1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done now by adding a property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channel-name>.consumer.binding-routing-key-delimiter=,
```

Then you can comma separate the routing keys:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channel-name>.consumer.binding-routing-key=key1,key2,key3
```

[Thanks Gary](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/pull/266)

[Reference documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_configuration_options)

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done with properties; but you can declare the additional bindings as beans; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526298/spring-boot-stream-bind-queue-with-multiple-routing-keys/50531872#50531872).

There is also a [third party "advanced" boot starter](https://github.com/societe-generale/rabbitmq-advanced-spring-boot-starter) that allows you to add declarations in a yaml file. I haven't tried it, but it looks interesting.