# Programmatically declare bindings in Spring Cloud Stream (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application what using the RabbitMQ binder to *consume* messages (it doesn't produce any). The `application.yaml` file looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          x:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: x.z.#
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
          y:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: y.z.#
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
      bindings:
        x:
          binder: rabbit
          group: q1
          destination: x
        y:
          binder: rabbit
          group: q2
          destination: y
```

This will create two queues in RabbitMQ:

1. `q1` that is bound to exchange `x` with routing key `x.z.#`
2. `q2` that is bound to exchange `y` with routing key `y.z.#`

I'd like to create a *single queue* that consumes from *multiple exchanges and routing keys*. I know that I can't bind an exchange to multiple routing keys from `application.yaml` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587227/multiple-bindingroutingkeys-for-a-consumer-with-spring-cloud-stream-using-rabbi) SO question) and thus I suspect that I can't configure Spring Cloud Stream to use multiple destinations (exchanges) for a single binding.

So my question is, can I programmatically declare so that one `binding` consumes from multiple exchanges? Is there anything that is required to be retained in the `application.yaml` file if doing this?

How should I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exchange-to-exchange binding to satisfy this requirement.

```
x -> z
y -> z
```

Then consume from a single queue on z that is bound with `#`.

You can define the exchange to exchange bindings in your boot application as `@Bean` s.